# Use seaborn object interface to plot overlapping density plots, added inside a for loop, each having its own color/label shown in a legend

Tags: python, seaborn, kdeplot, seaborn-0.12.x

Using seaborn python library, I am trying to make several density plots overlapping each other in the same figure and I want to color/label each of the lines. Using seaborn objects interface I am able to make the density plots within a for loop. But I cannot add color/label to each density plot.

I understand that there are other ways e.g., I create a dataframe with all the data and corresponding labels first and then pass it to seaborn plot(). But I was just wondering if below code (using seaborn objects interface) could work with some modifications. Please advise.

- **Plot using Seaborn objects**

Code:

Here I am setting color=s_n which is the number of samples that I drew from the normal distribution. I want to label each density plot with the number of samples (please also the see the desired plot towards the end of post)

```
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn.objects as so

num_samples = 2000
normal_distr = st.norm(1,1)

sp = so.Plot()

for s_n in range(10,num_samples,400):
    sample_normal = normal_distr.rvs(s_n)
    sp = sp.add(so.Line(),so.KDE(),x=sample_normal,color=s_n)
sp.show()
```

The plots looks like this and it does not color/label each density line separately.

[image: KDE plot without individual color for each density]

- **Desired Plot**

If I directly use seaborn kdeplot, I can get the desired plot (below). But I was just wondering if I can use seaborn objects instead of direct kdeplot

**Code using kdeplot:**

```
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num_samples = 2000
normal_distr = st.norm(1,1)

for s_n in range(10,num_samples,400):
    sample_normal = normal_distr.rvs(s_n)
    sns.kdeplot(x=sample_normal, label=s_n)    
plt.legend()
```

The (desired) plot:

[image: KDE plot with individual color for each density]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the trick here would be to prepare your df so that you can forgo the loop and use the color kwarg as it's [meant to be used](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.KDE.html):

```py
import scipy.stats as st
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd

num_samples = 2000
normal_distr = st.norm(1,1)

df = pd.concat([
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'sn': str(s_n),
        'values': normal_distr.rvs(s_n)}
        )
    for s_n in range(10,num_samples,400)
])
```

This would look like this:

```
        sn    values
0       10  0.976926
1       10 -0.501831
2       10  1.748071
3       10  0.968493
4       10  0.593531
...    ...       ...
1605  1610  0.311484
1606  1610  1.332424
1607  1610  1.531519
1608  1610  1.240953
1609  1610 -0.793144
```

Then printing can be done in a single line:

```py
so.Plot(df, x='values').add(so.Line(), so.KDE(common_norm=False), color='sn').show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I understand correctly, providing a vector for x (rather than a column name) works but not for color. In this line sp.add(so.Line(),so.KDE(),x=sample_normal,color=s_n) I provided direct values for both x and color. For x it worked and lines were drawn. But for colors it did not work because neither the lines have different color nor there is any legend.

Comment: You can also pass a vector for color. It's just more convenient to work with column names. This would work as well: `so.Plot(x=df['values']).add(so.Line(), so.KDE(common_norm=False), color=df['sn']).show()`